# Filter out all strings from a list that are a substring of another string in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a list of strings and want to remove every string which is a substring of another string. I'm trying to avoid an O(N^2) solution.

If I have a list such as

```
list = ['c', 'ca', 'cat', 'cat', 'd', 'do', 'dog', 'do']
```

I would like to receive the list

```
['cat', 'dog']
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've only tried solutions that are clearly flawed and not worth sharing

Comment: Please note that SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. If you have a specific problem with some code you've written, please post it, but if you aren't sure how to approach the task logically you need to step away from the computer and think it through on paper first.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Once this has an answer it will be here for everyone, I can't be the only one who's ever going to google this. I'll even answer it myself if I get the solution off SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const removeSubs = items => {
  const matches = text => test => text !== test && test.indexOf(text) > -1
  const cut = text => items.filter(matches(text)).length === 0
  
  return [...new Set(items.filter(cut))]
}

let list = ['c', 'ca', 'cat', 'cat', 'd', 'do', 'dog', 'do']

console.log(removeSubs(list))
```