# Remove all strings that are a substring of another string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Given this array:

```
['abc', 'defg', 'ab', 'jkl', 'ef']
```

I want to implement an algorithm that removes all strings that are substring of another string in the array.

```
'ab' is substring of 'abc'
'ef' is substring of 'defg'
```

The result should be `['abc', 'defg', 'jkl']`.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
  const removeSubstrings = (input: string[]): string[] => {
    if (input.length < 2) return input;
    const result = [...input];
    let i = 0;
    while (i < result.length - 1) {
      let j = i + 1;
      while (j < result.length && j > i) {
        if (result[i].includes(result[j])) {
            result.splice(j, 1);
        } else if (result[j].includes(result[i])) {
            result.splice(i, 1);
            j--;
        } else {
          j++;
        }
      }
      if (j > i) {
        i++;
      }
    }
    return result;
  };
```

Do you see any other shorter and performant algorithm (maybe using some pre-implemented js methods)?

Comment: Does your code work as expected? If yes, this question is off topic here and should be posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com? If no, what doesn't work?

Comment: Does preservation of order matter?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to belong at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @PeterSeliger no the order does not matter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter out all strings from a list that are a substring of another string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66698185/filter-out-all-strings-from-a-list-that-are-a-substring-of-another-string-in-an)

Comment: What if the array is `['abc', 'abc']`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland good question. The result should be ['abc']

Comment: It's more than a bit hokey, but you could do the following. 1. Sort the array by string length; 2. Join those strings separated by a space, to produce the string `'ab ef abc jkl defg'`; 3) Convert all substrings that match the regular expression `(\w+)(?= .*\1)` to empty strings, to obtain `'  abc jkl defg'`; and 4) extract from the string produced in the previous step all matches of the regular expression `\w+` to obtain `['abc', 'jkl', 'defg']`, the desired result...

Comment: ...The regular expression in step 3 reads, "match one or more word characters (`\w+`), saving that string to capture group 1 (`(\w+)`), with the *positive lookahead* (`(?= (?= .*\1) .*\1)`) asserting that the match is followed by a space followed by zero or more characters followed by the contents of capture group 1." [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ao0tlQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array by length and check if the actual string is not in one of the result set's strings.

```js
const
    removeSubstrings = array => array
        .sort(({ length: a }, { length: b }) => b - a)
        .reduce((r, s) => {
            if (!r.some(v => v.includes(s))) r.push(s);
            return r;
        }, []),
    data = ['abc', 'defg', 'ab', 'jkl', 'ef'],
    result = removeSubstrings(data);

console.log(result); // ['abc', 'defg', 'jkl']
```

Answer (score -1):

While not necessarily performant, you can use `Array#some` in the callback of `Array#filter`.

```js
function removeSubstrings(strs) {
  return strs.filter((s, i) => !strs.some((s2, j) => i !== j && s2.includes(s)));
}
console.log(removeSubstrings(['abc', 'defg', 'ab', 'jkl', 'ef']));
```

Answer (score -1):

To removes all the substrings from an array and only returns the strings that are not substrings of any other string in the input array:

**A simple approach to follow:**

- Loops through each string in the array using a *for loop* with a counter variable `i`.
- For each string at index `i`, a new variable boolean `isSubstring` is created and initialized to false.
- Do another for loop with a counter variable `j` is used to compare the string at index `i` with every other string in the input array.
- Check if the string at index `j` (other than the one at index `i`) includes the string at index `i`, then `isSubstring` is set to `true` and the inner loop is broken using `break;`.
- Then check if `isSubstring` is still `false`, then the string at index `i` is added to the result array using the `push()` method.

```js
function removeSubstrings(arr) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let isSubstring = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (i !== j && arr[j].includes(arr[i])) {
        isSubstring = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!isSubstring) {
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}


const arr = ['abc', 'defg', 'ab', 'jkl', 'ef'];
const result = removeSubstrings(arr);
console.log(result); // ['abc', 'defg', 'jkl']
```